# Uninitialized Constant Error in Nested Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant RegistrationsController
```

This is my log:

```
Started GET "/registrants/1/registrations/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-03 00:55:44 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RegistrationsController):

Rendered /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (8.5ms)
```

This is the part of my routes.rb that is appropriate:

```
registrant_registrations GET    /registrants/:registrant_id/registrations(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"registrations"}
                                   POST   /registrants/:registrant_id/registrations(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"registrations"}
       new_registrant_registration GET    /registrants/:registrant_id/registrations/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"registrations"}
      edit_registrant_registration GET    /registrants/:registrant_id/registrations/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"registrations"}
           registrant_registration GET    /registrants/:registrant_id/registrations/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"registrations"}
                                   PUT    /registrants/:registrant_id/registrations/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"registrations"}
```

This is my Registrations Controller, which is at `/app/controllers/portal/registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class Portal::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
        @registrant = current_member.registrants.find(params[:registrant])
        @registration = @registrant.registrations.build

        respond_to do |format|
          if @registration.save
            format.html {   redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Registration successfully created!" }
            format.json { head :ok }
          else
           format.html { redirect_to root_path, :notice => "There was a problem with the registration." }
          end
        end     
  end

end
```

I get this error when I call `new_registrant_registration_path(registrant)` from a view in `Portal#index`.

Edit:

For completeness, here is my routes.rb file in its entirety before the solution was found. Radar mentioned the gist I posted, but I figured I would put the code here in case that gist is deleted.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  match 'admin' => 'admin/dashboard#index', :as => :admin_root
  match 'portal' => 'portal#index', :as => :member_root

  namespace 'admin' do
    match 'profile' => 'profile#show', :as => :profile

    resources :members
    resources :admins
        resources :packages
        resources :products
        resources :levels
        resources :lessons
        resources :registrations
        resources :registrants, :controller => 'customers/registrants'
        resources :locations
        resources :schools
        resources :terms
        resources :customers
        resources :invoices
        resources :payments
  end

  namespace 'member' do
    resources :registrations
  end

  match 'register' => 'member/registrations#new', :as => :signup  
  match 'login' => 'member_sessions#new', :as => :login
  match 'logout' => 'member_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout  
  match 'admin/login' => 'admin_sessions#new', :as => :admin_login
  match 'admin/logout' => 'admin_sessions#destroy', :as => :admin_logout

  match 'member/activate/:activation_code' => 'member/activations#create', :as => :member_activation
  match 'member/:id/activate/resend' => 'member/activations#resend', :as => :resend_member_activation
  match 'member/:id/activate' => 'member/activations#new', :as => :new_member_activation

  match 'member/password/reset/begin' => 'member/password_resets#new', :as => :new_member_password_reset, :via => :get
  match 'member/password/reset' => 'member/password_resets#create', :as => :member_password_resets, :via => :post
  match 'member/password/:token/finish' => 'member/password_resets#edit', :as => :edit_member_password_reset, :via => :get
  match 'member/password/reset' => 'member/password_resets#update', :as => :member_password_reset, :via => :put

  match 'admin/packages/new/:partial' => 'admin/packages#new'

  resources :admins

  resources :registrants, :controller => 'portal/registrants' do
    resources :registrations
  end

  resource :admin_session
  resource :member_session

  root :to => 'portal#index'

end
```

Comment: Could you place the actual part of the routes.rb, who is responsible for registrant_registrations routes ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*To make things clear: marcamillion came into #rubyonrails and Freenode and [shared his `config/routes.rb`](https://gist.github.com/ebd4002ef068b10c9376). That's where I figured out the error that he was making and then figured out the answer.*

---

Two things.

#### First: Admin root route

Rather than defining the root route for your `admin` namespace like this:

```
match 'admin' => 'admin/dashboard#index', :as => :admin_root
```

Define it inside the `namespace :admin` call like this:

```
namespace 'admin' do
  root :to => "dashboard#index"
end
```

This will automatically define it as `admin_root_path` and `admin_root_url`, so you won't need to do that, and it will automatically prefix the controller with the `admin/` prefix, so you won't need to do that either.

#### Second: Referencing RegistrantsController

You have this currently in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :registrants, :controller => 'portal/registrants' do
  resources :registrations
end
```

What this will do is define resources routes for `registrants` correctly using the `Portal::RegistrantsController`, but *won't* define the nested routes underneath this using `Portal::RegistrationsController`. What it *will* do is attempt to use `RegistrationsController`, **which is why you're getting that error**.

To fix this, I'd recommend you use the `scope` method, like this:

```
scope :module => Portal do
 resources :registrants do
  resources :registrations
 end
end
```

The `scope` method, when used in this way, will tell Rails that the controllers for the routes inside the block are under the `Portal` namespace. This means that it will know that `resources :registrants` is for `Portal::Registrants` and that `resources :registrations` is for `Portal::Registrations`, thereby fixing the error that you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations...that makes total sense.

Comment: Downvoting this answer without commenting on it makes you a jackass, just FYI. Anonymous cowards.

Answer (score -2):

What if you change this line:

```
class Portal::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
```

to:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
```

?

Comment: `RegistrationsController` needs to live inside `Portal` because it's a part of the functionality of that namespace.

Answer (score -2):

This is strange. I think, your controller should be located at `/app/controllers/registrants/registrations_controller.rb` and looks like this:

```
class Registrants::RegistrationsController < Registrants::ApplicationController
  def create
    @registration = registrant.registrations.build

    ...
  end
end

class Registrants::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  def registrant
    current_member.registrants.find(params[:registrant_id])
  end
end
```

Registrants::ApplicationController (`/app/controllers/registrants/application_controller.rb`) controller aim is to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I have two namespaces, both of which handle registration differently. Oh, and also..the registration isn't of an individual user. Basically, a 'member' (which is a user in the `Member` namespace) has_many `registrants`. Those registrants have_many `registrations`. So this registration is associated with an individual registrant, which is associated with a member. Hence, this registrations controller being where it is...because `portal` is the view that a `member` sees when they login.

Comment: Fixing consequences or working your way around them is not the same as fixing the initial cause.

Comment: I downvoted. This answer is incorrect and won't fix the problem of it needing a `RegistrantsController`. See my answer for why and how to fix it.

Comment: @tanel-suurhans You are right. I should be asking to place routes.rb before I tried to answer this question.